# Popup in Shellcode

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, shellcode

I'm working on a project to insert shellcode into a pe file to do data popup. However I don't know how to convert from assembly to shellcode to get that string inserted into the section of PE file. I have the following assembly code:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL

include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc
include user32.inc

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib user32.lib

.data
Caption db "Message",0
Text db "Hello World",0

.code
start: push MB_OK
push offset Cat
push offset Text
push NULL
call MessageBox

push NULL
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Please help me :(((((((

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *convert from assembly to shellcode to get that string inserted into the section of PE file* but it's easy to convert assembly source to an portable executable file, which can be executed in Windows and popups a message box with text "Hello world" and button "OK". Both strings defined in the source will be  inserted into the `.data` section of PE file automatically, of course.

Save the following source as "Popup.asm", compile and link by [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/download/) with the command
`euroasm Popup.asm`, which will create PE file "Popup.exe".

```
Popup PROGRAM Format=PE,Model=FLAT,Entry=start:
        IMPORT MessageBoxA,Lib=user32.dll
        IMPORT ExitProcess,Lib=kernel32.dll
[.data]
Caption db "Message",0  
Text db "Hello World",0
MB_OK  EQU 0
NULL   EQU 0

[.code]
start: push MB_OK    
       push Caption
       push Text
       push NULL
       call MessageBoxA

       push NULL
       call ExitProcess  
     ENDPROGRAM
```

Comment: Do you not know what shellcode is?  It's a piece of machine code (and maybe data) that can be used with a code-injection exploit, e.g. a buffer overflow on an executable stack.  That means it has to be purely self-contained and position-independent, not dependent on any linker relocations to work at whatever address it runs from.  (And usually it also needs to avoid any `0` bytes in the code.)  Often you'd construct strings via `push imm32`, or by having them after the code and you store a `0` byte into them to make them into C strings.

Comment: The name "shellcode" comes from the most common payload: machine code that would make an `execve("/bin/sh", ..., ...)` system call, leaving a Unix *shell* connected to the TCP socket of the server you exploited.

Comment: So anyway, the main difficulty here is calling a DLL function from shellcode.  You'd have to know either the absolute address of the DLL function itself, or of some import table within the process you're exploiting.  Everything else is just a matter of arranging for args pointing to the right stuff to be on the stack when you run a `call`, and that's easy to construct with xor-zeroing, immediate `mov` / `push`, and `lea`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, so OP would have to search import tables of the infected executable at runtime. That's possible, because PE headers are mapped at the beginning of virtual address space and VA of ImportTable and of IAT are available in PE OptionalHeader. Import table has entries to the **names** of imported functions, and IAT has corresponding **addresses** of those functions, which were bound at loadtime. Indeed, that's a lot of work to do by an exploit.

Comment: PE headers are mapped at virtual address `0` (the start of virtual address space)?  So NULL deref doesn't fault??  Also, I thought Windows normally did ASLR anyway, so maybe the absolute addresses in those PE headers would only be useful for executables that disabled that, making them intentionally vulnerable to simpler exploits / simpler shellcode payloads.

Comment: @PeterCordes PE headers are mapped at ImageBase, which is usually 0x0040_0000. It starts with stub-file (signature "MZ") followed by "PE" signature, COFF file header, "PE" optional header, section headers. The `.text` raw contents usually begins at 0x0040_1000.

Comment: Is that address subject to ASLR along with the `.text` section and other static data?  Perhaps easier to make Windows system-calls directly, if you can guess what Windows kernel version the system is running (and thus what call number you can use), if that's possible for 32-bit code on a 64-bit kernel.  (Normal WOW64 involves a far call into 64-bit mode in user-space, for a DLL to make a `syscall` instruction, and IDK if a 64-bit Windows kernel would support a legacy `int 0x2e` or whatever other system-call ABI.)  Also, I'd guess that MessageBoxA is not just one system call.

Comment: @PeterCordes I run two instances of "popup.exe" in OllyDbg: `CALL ExitProcess` jumps to address in IAT with `FF242508304000` which is `JMP [&kernel32.ExitProcess]`.
The function in DLL performs `FF15DC1B6376` which is `CALL [&ntdll.RtlExitUserProcess]` and this kernel function finally ends with `E803560100` `CALL ZwTerminateProcess`, which jumps  by `FF2528921577` `JMP [Wow64Transition]` 
and `EA097002773300` `JMP FAR 0033:77027009`.  The bound virtual addresses are always the same (on Win10 20H2 64bits) for all instances.

Comment: Oh, well there you go, you could just hard-code one of those addresses into your shellcode with `mov eax, imm32` / `call eax`, since apparently Windows fails to ASLR everything and does have known contents at known addresses.  That makes even ROP attacks possible, where you can't inject code but can still take control of the return address.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, except for that Windows since Vista makes stack segment nonexecutable, which prevents your `mov eax,imm32` from execution in case of SO, as explained in [DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection#Windows).

Comment: Non-exec stacks are why I mentioned ROP attacks: injecting just return addresses, to send execution to "gadgets" that run a couple instructions ending with another `ret` to pop your next return address.  This lets you glue together some pieces of machine code from known addresses, eventually creating some state you want in registers (and maybe memory) before finally sending execution to a system-call wrapper function.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming.  Having known code at known addresses makes this much easier than if everything is ASLRed.